# Properity of algebraic multiplicity of irreducible matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

If a matrix $A \geq 0$ is an irreducible matrix in $M_n(R)$, for $B \geq A$, but $B \neq A$.

How to prove the algebraic multiplicity of $B$ is always greater than $A$ ?

I thought it is clear that $(B-A) \geq 0 $ , but I am not sure how to continue...

Comment: What do you means by $B\ge A$?

Comment: @EmilioNovati, $B = (b_{ij}), A= (a_{ij}) $, $b_{ij} \geq a_{ij}, \forall i, j$

Comment: What doe you mean by the "algebraic multiplicity of $B$"?  This isn't how that terminology is usually used.